# Efficient Way to Vectorize a Function over each Row of a Data-Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vectorization

I have a data frame where one column is a list of time-stamps. I need to annotate which time-stamps are valid or not, depending on whether or not they are close enough (i.e., within 1 second) to an element of another list of valid time-stamps. For this I have a helper function.

```
valid_times <- c(219.934, 229.996, 239.975, 249.935, 259.974, 344)

actual_times <- c(200, 210, 215, 220.5, 260)
strain <- c("green", "green", "green", "green", "green", "green")
valid_or_not <- c(rep("NULL", 6))

df <- data.frame(strain, actual_times, valid_or_not)
```

My data-frame looks like this:

```
strain actual_times valid_or_not
1 green 200.0        NULL
2 green 210.0        NULL
3 green 215.0        NULL
4 green 220.5        NULL
5 green 260.0        NULL
```

My helper (that checks to see if an actual_time is within 1 second of a valid time) is as follows:

```
valid_or_not_fxn<- function(actual_time){
c = "not valid"
for (i in 1:length(valid_times))
if (abs(valid_times[i] - actual_time) <= 1) {
c <- "valid"
} else {
}
return(c)
```

}

What I've tried to do is loop through the entire data-frame using a for loop with this helper function.

However....it's really slow (on my real data-set) because it's a nested loop cross-comparing two lists that are 100s of elements long. **I can't figure out to optimize this.**

```
df$valid_or_not <- as.character(df$valid_or_not)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) 
  print(df[i, "valid_or_not"])
  df[i, "valid_or_not"] <- valid_or_not_fxn(df[i, "actual_times"])
```

**Thank you for any help!**

Comment: No matter what you do, you essentially have to do at least `length(valid_times)` comparisons. Probably better off looping over `valid_times` and comparing each item of that vector to your `actual_times` column as a vectorised operation. That way you'd only have 5 loop iterations.

Comment: `data.table::inrange(actual_times, valid_times - 1, valid_times + 1)` for a possible vectorized solution

Comment: @DavidArenburg - I knew there was probably a fancy data.table solution, but it wasn't coming to me. I'm sure `lapply` and `Reduce` isn't super fast but it copes okay with mid-size data.

Comment: @thelatemail I'm not sure `inrange` is covering all scenarios though. It's 2:37 am and I'm going asleep...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what you do, you essentially have to do at least `length(valid_times)` comparisons. Probably better off looping over `valid_times` and comparing each item of that vector to your `actual_times` column as a vectorised operation. That way you'd only have 5 loop iterations.

One way of doing this is then:

```
df$test <- Reduce(`|`, lapply(valid_times, function(x) abs(df$actual_times - x) <= 1))

#  strain actual_times valid_or_not
#1  green        200.0        FALSE
#2  green        210.0        FALSE
#3  green        215.0        FALSE
#4  green        220.5         TRUE
#5  green        260.0         TRUE
```

100K rows in `df` and 1000 `valid_times` test finishes in <4 seconds:

```
df2 <- df[sample(1:5,1e5,replace=TRUE),]
valid_times2 <- valid_times[sample(1:5,1000,replace=TRUE)]
system.time(Reduce(`|`, lapply(valid_times2, function(x) abs(df2$actual_times - x) <= 1)))
# user  system elapsed 
# 3.13    0.40    3.54
```

Answer (score 2):

The easist way to do it is avoiding data frame operations. So you can do this check and populate the valid_or_not vector before combining them into the dataframe as:

```
valid_or_not[sapply(actual_times, function(x) any(abs(x - valid_times) <= 1))] <- "valid"
```

Note that, by this line, the valid_or_not vector is indexed with an equal length vector of boolean values (whether the condition is satisfied, T or F). So only TRUE valued indices from the vector are updated. valid_or_not and actual_times vectors must be of same length where as valid_times vector can be of different length.

By the way "plying" a for loop does not enhance the performance significantly since it is just a "wrapper" for "for" loops. Only performance increase comes from avoiding intermediary objects due to neater and more concise style of code and avoiding redundant copying in some cases. The same case is true for the Vectorize function: It just wraps the for loop that goes through the function and in for example "outer" function, the FUN must be "vectorized" in that manner. In fact it does not give the performance of a truely vectorized operation. In my example the performance enhancement comes from the substitution of the for loop with the "any" function.

And because of some kind of a "bug", subsetting data frames has an important penalty. As [Hadley Wickham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16632/hadley) explains in [Performance](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html) topic of Advanced-R:

> Extracting a single value from a data frame
>
> The following microbenchmark shows five ways to access a single value
>   (the number in the bottom-right corner) from the built-in mtcars
>   dataset. The variation in performance is startling: the slowest method
>   takes 30x longer than the fastest. There’s no reason that there has to
>   be such a huge difference in performance. It’s simply that no one has
>   had the time to fix it.
>
> ```
> microbenchmark(
>    "[32, 11]"      = mtcars[32, 11],
>    "$carb[32]"        = mtcars$carb[32],
>    "[[c(11, 32)]]" = mtcars[[c(11, 32)]],
>    "[[11]][32]"    = mtcars[[11]][32],
>    ".subset2"      = .subset2(mtcars, 11)[32] )
>
>
>
> ## Unit: nanoseconds
> ##           expr    min     lq  mean median     uq     max neval
> ##       [32, 11] 15,300 16,300 18354 17,000 17,800  76,400   100
> ##      $carb[32]  8,860  9,930 12836 10,600 11,600  85,400   100
> ##  [[c(11, 32)]]  7,200  8,110  9293  8,780  9,350  21,300   100
> ##     [[11]][32]  6,330  7,580  8377  8,100  8,690  20,900   100
> ##       .subset2    334    566  4461    669    800 368,000   100
> ```

The most efficient way to subset a data frame is to use the .subset2 method. Your poor performance can mostly be attributed to this fact.

And as last notes:

- If the "else" in your conditional statment does not do anything (just like in your example: else {}) you do not have to include it. R has some lazy operations (does not evaluate a statement as long as it is not executed inside the code), but that does not mean it always skips non-executed code portions.
- The "character" values in your example are in fact categoric: Only
  one of few values can be chosen for each entry. So there is no need
  to store them as "characters" and they can be converted into factors
  (which are just [integer values](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/classes/s133/factors.html)). This can also enhance
  performance.

An addition for @thelatemail 's working solution:

- In R, "or" (|) operator isn't lazy while "any" function is. A ply combining or's work till the end while "any" function stops at the first encounter of a TRUE value - which enhances the performance (I will write a blog post on this topic ASAP). And vectorized "any" is almost as fast as native C code while *ply can be slightly faster than for loops in R (That I will benchmark and show in another blog post soon).

Some benchmarks showing this:

Pure "any" and | comparison:

```
> microbenchmark(any(T,F,F,F,F,F), T|F|F|F|F|F)                                                                                                                                               
Unit: nanoseconds                              
                  expr min    lq   mean median    uq   max neval cld                           
 any(T, F, F, F, F, F) 274 307.0 545.86  366.5 429.5 16380   100   a                           
 T | F | F | F | F | F 597 626.5 903.47  668.5 730.0 18966   100   a
```

Pure "Reduce" and vectorization comparison:

```
> vec0 <- rep(1, 1e6)
> microbenchmark(Reduce("+", vec0), sum(vec0), times = 10)
Unit: microseconds
              expr        min         lq        mean      median         uq
 Reduce("+", vec0) 308415.064 310071.953 318503.6048 312940.6355 317648.354
         sum(vec0)    930.625    936.775    944.2416    943.5425    949.257
        max neval cld
 369864.993    10   b
    962.349    10  a
```

And a reduced "|" vs. vectorized "any" comparison (for an extreme case). "any" beats by more than 1e5 times:

```
> vec1 <- c(T, rep(F, 1e6))
> microbenchmark(Reduce("|", vec1), any(vec1), times = 10)
Unit: nanoseconds
              expr       min        lq        mean    median        uq
 Reduce("|", vec1) 394040518 395792399 402703632.6 399191803 400990304
         any(vec1)       154       267      1932.5      2588      2952
       max neval cld
 441805451    10   b
      3420    10  a
```

When the single TRUE is at the very end (so "any" is not lazy anymore and has to check the whole vector), "any" still beats by more than 400 times:

```
> vec2 <- c(rep(F, 1e6), T)
> microbenchmark(Reduce("|", vec2), any(vec2), times = 10)
Unit: microseconds
              expr        min         lq        mean     median         uq
 Reduce("|", vec2) 396625.318 401744.849 416732.5087 407447.375 424538.222
         any(vec2)    736.975    787.047    857.5575    832.137    926.076
        max neval cld
 482116.632    10   b
   1013.732    10  a
```

Comment: Hi, maybe I'm missing something?, but this solution doesn't work if the length of valid_times does not equal that of actual_times. 
With `valid_or_not[abs(valid_times - actual_times) <= 1] <- "valid"`
 


I get  `"Warning message: In c(219.934, 229.996, 239.975, 249.935, 259.974) - c(200, 210,  :  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"`

Comment: True! I got it wrong at first, but now I corrected it with the correct form. I also modified my explanations accordingly. Please notify me whether it works now.

Comment: By the way @thelatemail follows a similar approach and it works also, however in his case two performance issues are missing:  The solution combines or ("|") operators with a ply. *Ply functions are not as fast as true vectorized functions. And or operator is not lazy while any is: Which means "any" function stops when the first "TRUE" is encountered while in "or" all comparisons are executed till the last one.

Comment: @SerhatCevikel - the `any` and the `|` 'or' do not give the same result though. Compare `sapply(valid_times, function(x) any(x - actual_times <= 1))` and `Reduce(\`|\`,lapply(valid_times, function(x) (x - actual_times) <= 1))`

Comment: Sorry for my code, there were two mistakes: I forgot to "abs" the difference, and I swapped the actual and valid times. Now I corrected it both codes return the same. But I'll include the penalty of "reduce" against vectorization and "|" against "any" as an additional note in my post.

Comment: Interesting - I was thinking that if `df` was huge and `valid_times` was much smaller that it would be a huge penalty to loop over each row. But it seems that doesn't pan out.

Comment: Well, for example, for a 2 boolean value case, "|" is faster than "any", but after adding a few booelan values, "any" starts to perform much better as I showed above. So even for a 5 boolean values case, "any" can perform twice better in case a TRUE is encountered at the first item.